# How do I detect simultaneous touches on UI elements in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, multi-touch

I'm new to WP7 and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  In the code below I create a bunch of rectangle and then toggle thier color when touched.  The trouble is that when I touch two rectangles at the same time only one gets an event.  I assume this is because I'm using the mouse event but I don't see a touch event to hook up to.  Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant XAML

```
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <toolkit:WrapPanel  x:Name="RectWrapPanel" Height="768" Width="480"/>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace colortouch
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        SolidColorBrush blueBrush = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Colors.Blue };
        SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Colors.Red };
        SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Colors.Black };

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.Height = 50;
                rect.Width = 50;

                rect.Stroke = blackBrush;
                rect.Fill = blueBrush;

                //rect.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rect_MouseLeftButtonDown);
                rect.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(rect_MouseEnter);
                Button b = new Button();

                RectWrapPanel.Children.Add(rect);
            }
        }

        void rect_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;

            if (rect.Fill == blueBrush)
                rect.Fill = redBrush;
            else
                rect.Fill = blueBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Manipulation events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider Touch Panel and Gestures for your requirements.

[Working with Touch Input (Windows Phone)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx)

[WP7 Tip of the Day: Silverlight Toolkit: Gestures](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/01/WP7-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-Gestures.aspx)